# Why haven't I gotten the Extra Toppings hat?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2017

I recently [posted this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48044625/5647260) on Stack Overflow and to my knowledge it meets the criteria for Extra Toppings:

- Has > +3 score
- Competing with already accepted answer
- Answer & Question were after Winterbash started

Could it be that I answered a day after the competing answer was accepted or that I've hit the rep cap? I was thinking maybe the hat check hadn't run but someone has already received the Glasses With A Number On Top while meeting the criteria after me. Are there some hidden criteria?

This has got to be a bug with Stack Overflow, because [this post](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/64805/mention-signing-bonus-from-current-company-in-salary-negotiations-with-new-compa/104487#104487) from Workplace.SE triggered the hat, and the competing answer was posted a year after the original one. [This post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/103434/how-to-add-different-colors-to-multiple-segments-in-a-circle/103437#103437) from Graphic Design.SE also triggered the hat and the poster got the hat within 30 minutes of the post (the linked post was originally unaccepted). [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305256/why-havent-i-gotten-the-extra-toppings-hat#comment992248_305256) tried to get the hat on Stack Overflow but didn't get it and was eventually disqualified due to it being accepted.

Comment: It is caching. Give it 6 to 8 weeks ...

Comment: Might be a bug, e.g. script isn't taking the net score but rather only upvotes, and since you hit rep cap, the upvotes are nullified. Or something like that. :)

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard I was thinking that might be the case but it seems odd for them to depend on rep gained than actual score.

Comment: Yeah, that's a long shot, I'll give it few more hours before calling it a bug. Maybe the script for this hat is running on bigger intervals as it needs to process more data, not sure about it.

Comment: On a different note, if you'll get the hat you'll become #1 on the Leader board, so... good luck! ;)

Comment: Watching this with interest too, I’d have thought I earned the hat with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045518/class-variable-as-instance-of-enclosing-class/48050501#48050501) but it hasn’t been awarded.

Comment: And I am now disqualified for the hat because the OP switched the accepted answer mark to mine. Which gives us a hint that there probably is a delay to the hat award to ensure your competiting answer stays a competing answer for a minimum amount of time first.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, there's only a good day and a half left of WB...

Comment: @Andrew: criteria like these (minimal score, a minimal time on the site, etc.) have traditionally been implicit for WB hats.

Comment: I'm the author of the Workplace post, and I got the hat within an hour of the third upvote.

Comment: Note: that it doesn't disqualify if it is accepted (I got it after my post was accepted) as long as the (2nd) post was posted *after* the 1st one was accepted. [even if it got accepted later - even if before you got the hat]

Comment: And it can't be SO not included... A bunch of users got it there.

Comment: @WELZ The bug maybe cropped up two days ago?

Comment: @Rob I vtc'd as dupe but it's not closing the question? I haven't been incredibly active, has closing changed?

Comment: Andrew, refresh the page and there's supposed to be a banner that asks if it solves your problem, when you choose yes it closes immediately (adding the Community user as a close voter if we have fewer than 5).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry about that, turns out the query has been timing out for a few days. I am rolling out a fix now, so the hats should award shortly.

Comment: :-D That explains the sudden awarding. Double kudos for handing out mine even though the qualifying answer has since been marked accepted! <3

Comment: @MartijnPieters The actual check doesn't care if the accepted answer got changed, only that another answer was accepted when you posted. ;P

Comment: @animuson Thanks for ruining the illusion of my generosity. :P